# Yii2: как профилировать rest api?

Tags: yii2

Как профилировать REST API в Yii2? Где смотреть результаты профилирования?
Если с обычной web-мордой все ясно, то в API уже панель debug не прикрутишь к ответу сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же как в web-версии.

1. Отправляем запрос используя api:
   [image]
2. Переходим в дебаг(по адресу site.com/debug)
   [image]

Так же в эту панель можно попасть из web'а, нажав на логотип yii
[image]

Примечание:
У вас должен быть включен режим отладки - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36284862/5285604